# Send O365 logs to on-prem SIEM

Tags: office365api

We are trying to send the O365 logs to our on-prem SIEM.

We went to aad.portal.azure.com -> azure active directory -> App registrations then add permission for Microsoft Graph and O365 Management APIs. The status is granted.

However, we are getting this error- {'error': {'code': 'AF20023', 'message': 'The subscription was disabled.'}}

Which subscription is disabled? We have a valid license for O365 and Azure active directory.

Or is it the right way to send O365 logs to on-prem SIEM?

Thanks.

Ymed

Comment: Got exactly the same issue..

Answer (score 0):

Probably the cert has expired...
I needed to integrate O365 into QRadar and followed this doc.

https://documentation.wazuh.com/current/cloud-security/office365/monitoring-office365-activity.html#office-365-api-requirements